# Erros installing the FFTW library

Tags: macos, installation, libraries

I need to install the FFTW library on Mac OX X 10.8.

If I execute

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/
```

in Bash, I get

```
checking how to get verbose linking output from /usr/local/scisoft//packages/iraf/iraf/unix/hlib//f77.sh... configure: WARNING: compilation failed
checking for Fortran 77 libraries of /usr/local/scisoft//packages/iraf/iraf/unix/hlib//f77.sh...  -L/usr/local/scisoft/lib/' -L/usr/local/scisoft/lib/ -lm
checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... none
checking for Fortran 77 name-mangling scheme... configure: error: in `/Users/FiorellaCagnetta/ZEST+/Libraries/fftw-3.3.3':
configure: error: cannot compile a simple Fortran program
See `config.log' for more details
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any fortran compiler installed (gfortran...)? I mean:

```
error: cannot compile a simple Fortran program
```

is kinda clear.

Plus, it is said there: http://www.fftw.org/install/mac.html that `Fink` have `fftw3` available (http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/fftw3)

Comment: So what do you suggest to do? try to install a fortran compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This will fix it - Install gfortran first. I used

```
brew install gfortran
```

Then, pass the `F77=gfortran` parameter to the fftw `.configure`